# Расположение блоков css как на фото

Tags: css, flexbox, background-image

Всем привет, как мне расположить эту иконку с собачьей лапой поверх фотографии как на этом скриншоте? Спасибо)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как мне расположить эту иконку с собачьей лапой поверх фотографии как на этом скриншоте?

Например вот так... Вместо картинок я использовал фоновый цвет.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
```